# Increasing every number in a CSV by one?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

This might be obvious to some people, but I have CSV data that I'm storing as a String in which every number is off by -1. I'd like to write a function (in ActionScript 3) in which I go in and increase every value by +1. How can I do this?

My CSV String looks like this:

```
public static const CSV_DATA:String = "14,15,16,8,9,8,9,8,9,8,9,264,265,266,267,268,269,8,9,260,261,262,263,8,9,1,2,3\n" +
"32,33,34,26,27,26,27,26,27,26,27,282,283,284,285,286,287,26,27,278,279,280,281,26,27,19,20,21\n" +
... etc
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you doing this because you're planning on reading CSV data, or do you not understand how to use arrays?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, just use `String.split()`. Primary split string by '\n', secondary split by ','. In result array every string with number process with `parseInt` function. After that, you can increase your numbers by one.

But if you need to read real CSV files, you can write class for this or use [open-source](https://github.com/NeoPhi/AS3CSV)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var CSV_DATA:String = "14,15,16,8,9,8,9,8,9,8,9,264,265,266,267,268,269,8,9,260,261,262,263,8,9,1,2,3,32,33,34,26,27,26,27,26,27,26,27,282,283,284,285,286,287,26,27,278,279,280,281,26,27,19,20,21";


var UPDATED_CSV_DATA:String = addOne(CSV_DATA);

function addOne(CSV:String):String
{
 var CSVArr:Array = CSV.split(",");

 for(var i=0;i<CSVArr.length;i++)
 {
     CSVArr[i] = Number(CSVArr[i]) + 1 ;

 }
 return CSVArr.toString();
}
```